# qTip2: using relative Div-container as qTip content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, qtip, qtip2

Can I define a relative div to be used as content for qTip2?
Here's a fiddle, that should show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0p1mgdse/

```
content: {
    text: $(this).parents(".item").find('.qtip-content-container')
},
```

...is not working to show the correspondent div (since it's a lot of those "items" in the real code, I can't use absolute divs as content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself, the .qtip() had to be called via this encapsuled in an each():

```
$('a.qtip-title-readinglist').each(function() {
     $(this).qtip({
     ....
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ovstne29/

Answer (score 1):

test it

[https://jsfiddle.net/0p1mgdse/1/ ][1]

```
content: {
        text: $('a.qtip-title-readinglist').parents(".item").find('.qtip-content-container')
    }
```